# (404)Error when trying to store data with route endpoint

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm attempting to store user data when they register.  I'm using a simple form in react.  Node/express for the back end.

I'm getting a 404 not found error.

Caveat--

I have in my client's package.json a proxy set to my server port:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

and my client runs on port 3000 (I'm using create-react-app)

Here is the form logic:

```
    createUser(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newUser = {
            name: this.state.name,
            password: this.state.password,
            zip: this.state.zip
        }

        axios.post('./api/users/register', newUser)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Here is the route logic from the backend:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    // const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body);

    // // Check Validation
    // if (!isValid) {
    //   return res.status(400).json(errors);
    // }

    // User.findOne({ name: req.body.name }).then(user => {
    //   if (user) {
    //     errors.name = 'Name already exists';
    //     return res.status(400).json(errors);
    //   } else {

        const newUser = new User({
          name: req.body.name,
          password: req.body.password,
          zip: req.body.zip
        });

        newUser
          .save()
          .then(user => res.json(newUser))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));

        // bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        //   bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        //     if (err) throw err;
        //     newUser.password = hash;
        //     newUser
        //       .save()
        //       .then(user => res.json(newUser))
        //       .catch(err => console.log(err));
        //   });
        // });
      //}
  //   });
  });
```

And this is the error I receive from the browser:

```
xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/register 404 (Not Found)

Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createError (createError.js:16)
at settle (settle.js:18)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

---

I understand that even though I'm seeing the error for

```
http://localhost:3000/api/users/register
```

that my proxy should still be in affect..  As per this discussion here:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1219

--- A comment from this discussion:

"It does look like you're getting 400 ERROR. Doesn't this mean the request gets proxied (but server fails for some reason)?

The request would appear to be to 3000 port in the browser because that's the point of the proxy feature. It is needed so that browser lets us make the request without enabling CORS on that server. However the actual request gets proxied so while you see it as a request to 3000, CRA will pipe it to 8080 port instead, undetectable to the app itself."

Comment: It's not clear in your question: are you sending proxied requests to port 5000 or port 8080?

Comment: At the top of the question I have the line of code I'm using, to port 5000.

The bottom quotation is from the github discussion.  I'll modify it to make it more clear.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't cleat to me. Can you access http://localhost:5000/api/users/register?

Comment: Yes I'm able to store users successfully using postman via this route

Comment: Have you tried removing the leading dot in your XHR request, and using an absolute path instead? Like `axios.post('/api/users/register', newUser)`?

Comment: I just tried it, receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

*I also I get that same error last month.*

**But I solve that by calling in My server.js(app.js) in express I think u will get it  if u do this**

see my code below

```
`axios.post('/sqladd',{
            year : this.state.year,
            multi : this.state.multiyear
           }).then(function(response){
            // window.alert("Data Inserted to SQL DB !");
            // window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/";
           }).catch(function(error){
            //toastr.clear();
            //toastr.error(error);
           });`
```

this is sending the data to the database it is in react file (client folder)

```
var control =require("./controllers/framcontroller.js");

app.post('/sqladd',control.farm_add);
```

it is on the server means in the express folder(app.js file)

As I m using a controller so I m given the path as the control name

```
module.exports.farm_add = (req,res)=>{ 
 let year = req.body.year;
 let multi = req.body.multi;
 let post = {name:year, address:multi};
 let sql = 'INSERT INTO customers SET ?';
 let query = con.query(sql,post,(err,result)=>{
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
  res.send('New data added..');
});
```

this is my database operation.

*if any other problem is there then let me know*

Thank you